# Android Studio error - Invalid Revision 24.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, version

[image]

I am getting this version issue !
Please help

Comment: Some more details?

Comment: share the error statements

Comment: check here you use 24.0.0 -alpha

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't have the "local.properties" file in the project folder. Adding it got the project make it working again successfully.

In the file should be something like:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\blabla\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your code has a dependency on Android `24.0.0-alpha1`, but your build script is using revision 23.  I think a quick fix would be changing the SDK versions in your Gradle build script to 24 or higher:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 24
```

Comment: Please mark correct if it solved your problem, thanks.